# How to mark mail undeliverable in Outlook 2010

Tags: blackberry, outlook-2010, email

I have just recently taken over a position of an ex-employee and all of his email now gets forwarded to me. Unfortunately he was part of a mailing list that receives error messages when his websites experience database problems. I also currently receive all work related email on my blackberry. Quite frankly I am quite tired of waking up every morning and having to delete 20+ email messages on my phone.

I was told there was some way to mark certain email addresses as undeliverable to where they fill up a specified folder and don't get sent to my blackberry. Does anyone know how to create these rules or boundaries in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a third party spam filtering service, you can probably add certain email addresses or even entire domains to a blacklist that will be rejected before it even gets to your mail server.

Assuming you have Exchange, you could also create a rule in Outlook to move messages that meet certain criteria to a different folder that isn't sync'ed with your BlackBerry (it only does Inbox and Sent Items by default), or even just delete them.

Comment: Your second answer applied to my scenario quite well. I just created a rule that applied to those kind of emails. They get filed away when I receive a message and don't get sent to my blackberry. Thanks.